# Null reference exception when running

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

i am getting the null reference exception when running the following code.i have created a class where return a collection of objects.Printing the values in the main class.

```
//main class where i am calling employee class.
class Program
    {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //Creating an object for employee class.
                Employees obje = new Employees();
                var obj2 = obje.EmployeeDetails();

                //looping through each object and printing the values.
                foreach (var emp in obj2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(emp.Employeeid);
                    Console.WriteLine(emp.Employeename);
                    Console.WriteLine(emp.Employeeage);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }


    //Employee class with some properties and function. 
     class Employees
        {
            public int Employeeid { get; set; }
            public string Employeename { get; set; }
            public string Employeeage { get; set; }


            public Employees[] EmployeeDetails()
            {
                Employees[] objEmployees = new Employees[2];

                objEmployees[0].Employeeage = "20";
                objEmployees[0].Employeeid = 101;
                objEmployees[0].Employeename = "Arjunan";

                objEmployees[1].Employeeage = "24";
                objEmployees[1].Employeeid = 102;
                objEmployees[1].Employeename = "Shiva";

                return objEmployees;
            }
        }
```

Please tell me where i am doing mistake.am newbie to the dotnet world.

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: This is where i am getting null reference exception.   objEmployees[0].Employeeage = "20";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
    public Employees[] EmployeeDetails()
    {
        Employees[] objEmployees = new Employees[2];
        objEmployees[0] = new Employees();//Note to the new instance
        objEmployees[0].Employeeage = "20";
        objEmployees[0].Employeeid = 101;
        objEmployees[0].Employeename = "Arjunan";

        objEmployees[1] = new Employees();//Note to the new instance
        objEmployees[1].Employeeage = "24";
        objEmployees[1].Employeeid = 102;
        objEmployees[1].Employeename = "Shiva";

        return objEmployees;
    }
```

You have to instantiate your array items with new object (`Employees`) before accessing them, otherwise, it would be equals to `null` reference.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create element of an array with `new` keyword.

```
 objEmployees[0] = new Employees();
 objEmployees[0].Employeeage = "20";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Employees` is a `class`. That's why it is a *reference type*. And if you create an array with a reference type, all array items initialized to `null` as a default.

That means your `objEmployees[0]` is `null` as a default and you try to set null's property. That's why you get [`NullReferanceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From [`Arrays (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)

> The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, **and
>   reference elements are set to null.**

As a solution, you might need to create a new `Employees` object (with `new` keyword) for your array items or you can use an array initializer like *[tvanfosson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970133/447156)*.

Answer (score 0):

Employees[] objEmployees = new Employees[2]; // This creates the array not the items in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the Employees class in the array before setting the values:

```
        public Employees[] EmployeeDetails()
    {
        Employees[] objEmployees = new Employees[2];

        objEmployees[0] = new Employees();
        objEmployees[0].Employeeage = "20";
        objEmployees[0].Employeeid = 101;
        objEmployees[0].Employeename = "Arjunan";

        objEmployees[1] = new Employees();
        objEmployees[1].Employeeage = "24";
        objEmployees[1].Employeeid = 102;
        objEmployees[1].Employeename = "Shiva";

        return objEmployees;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Employees[] EmployeeDetails()
            {
                Employees[] objEmployees = new Employees[2];

                objEmployees[0].Employeeage = "20";
                objEmployees[0].Employeeid = 101;
                objEmployees[0].Employeename = "Arjunan";

                objEmployees[1].Employeeage = "24";
                objEmployees[1].Employeeid = 102;
                objEmployees[1].Employeename = "Shiva";

                return objEmployees;
            }
```

This method is causing the problem. When you create the array of `Employees`, all you are doing is allocating memory. You haven't actually created any `Employees` objects and placed them in the array.

So when you try to do `objEmployees[0].Employeeage = "20"`, you are getting a NullReference exception because no `Employees` object exists at `objEmployees[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating the array, but you're not creating the objects in the array before you attempt to use them.  In this case a better way to handle it would be to use an array initializer.

```
 return new []
 {
     new Employee
     {
         EmployeeAge = 20,
         EmployeeId = 101,
         EmployeeName = "Arjunan",
     },
     new Employee
     {
         EmployeeAge = 24,
         EmployeeId = 102,
         EmployeeName = "Shiva",
     },
 };
```

Note I've made the names of the properties follow PascalCase and assumed that the age property really should be numeric, not string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 public Employees[] EmployeeDetails()
    {
        var objEmployees = new Employees[2];
        objEmployees[0] = new Employees();
        objEmployees[0].Employeeage = "20";
        objEmployees[0].Employeeid = 101;
        objEmployees[0].Employeename = "Arjunan";

        objEmployees[1] = new Employees();
        objEmployees[1].Employeeage = "24";
        objEmployees[1].Employeeid = 102;
        objEmployees[1].Employeename = "Shiva";



        return objEmployees;

    }
```

You need to create an instance for each objEmployees